# Javascript library to simulate Windows 8 look and feel

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, javascript, look-and-feel

Is there a good JavaScript library that enables the easy simulation of the Windows 8 look and feel for web-based applications? I'm thinking of things like tiling, flat boxes, etc.

EDIT: I just found out that the Windows 8 UI style is called Metro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to use JQuery you can use Metro JS. A javascript plugin for JQuery.

Live tiles, Application bar, ect...

More info here: http://www.drewgreenwell.com/projects/metrojs

Comment: Thanks, I also found http://metroui.org.ua/ which looks promising.